# Angular.js routing fails to work within Trigger.io app on some Android devices

Tags: android, angularjs, angular-ui-router, trigger.io

I am developing an angular.js-based application using trigger.io, and everything works well except on some Android devices (e.g. Nexus 5) where I run into this issue: angular routes never get loaded and the default page and controller remain active. How can I fix this?

Below is a simple scenario. Page 1 contains a link that should load page 2.

I have the expected behavior on:

- iOS
- Web
- Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini running Android 4.1.1
- Android when running Live Forge (serve)

Page 2 does not get loaded when the link is clicked on:

- Any device/simulator running Android 4.4 KitKat (and also other Android versions)

I've tried:

- Using the ngRoute module instead of ui.router. The same problem occurs.
- Using previous Trigger.io platform versions
- Changing dynamically the default route with `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page2')`, this changes the route, but is not a viable solution
- Changing the url using `window.url = '#/page2'` ⇒ `window.url` remains `...#/page1`.

Any help/suggestion is welcome!

## Simple scenario:

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### js/main.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('page1', {
      url: '/page1',
      template: '<h1>This is page 1</h1><p><a href="#/page2">Go to page 2</a></p>'
    })
    .state('page2', {
      url: '/page2',
      template: '<h1>This is page 2</h1><p><a href="#/page1">Go to page 1</a></p>'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular routing breaks quite dramatically on Android KitKat due to the switch from the old Android WebView to Chrome WebView.

So far the only reliable approach we know of is to use the ui-router and navigate with either ui-sref or $state.go() in the controller.

Also see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref